# Passing Java object into closure template?

Tags: java, google-closure-templates

As far as I know, Google Closure Template doesn't allow passing Java object into the template (as compared to [FreeMarker](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/pgui_datamodel_objectWrapper.html)). So I can't really do something like:

```
// Java file
class Course {
  ...
  public function getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

// Main function
public static void main(String args[]) {
  // Get all courses
  List<Course> courses = Courses.getAllCourses();
  Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  params.put("courses", courses);

  String out = tofu.newRenderer("template.listCourses").setData(params);
}

// Soy file
/**
 * @param courses List of courses
 */
{template .listCourses}
  Courses List! <br/>

  {foreach $course in $courses}
        New Course: {$course.name}
  {/foreach}
{/template}
```

I'm thinking if I want to do this I probably have to write a custom function that uses Reflection to turn Course object into a Map? I'm not experienced with Java Reflection. Is there such a function available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In plovr, I created a utility, [SoyDataUtil.java](http://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/browse/src/org/plovr/util/SoyDataUtil.java), which takes a [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) and converts it into a [SoyData](http://closure-templates.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc-lite/com/google/template/soy/data/SoyData.html). Admittedly, you may only find this useful if you are already using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), but the nice thing about this approach is that Gson is likely to take care of the getter/setter reflection for you. For example, I believe you should be able to do:

```
JsonElement json = (new Gson()).toJsonTree(courses);
SoyData soyData = SoyDataUtil.jsonToSoyData(json); 

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("courses", soyData);
```

The trick is leveraging Gson to do to the reflection to turn `courses` into a `JsonElement`. Not sure whether you're willing to add these dependencies (though the code from plovr is quite small -- you can just copy it directly), but this may be the most expedient solution.

Comment: initilaizing params.put statement is fine, next, how can i pass this value(soydata) to templates.